# submit button has to redirect to the selected radio button page in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with my form. I need it to redirect user to different pages basing on which radio button was selected. User has to choose one of two options and click GO, and according to his choice, page should redirect him to other page. for example if he selected male option go button have to redirect to male page

Here is the code as it looks for now

```
const gender = () => {
  
 

  

  
  return (
    <div className="content-page">
      <div className="card-box pt-3">
        <div className="card-body">
          
          <Accordion defaultActiveKey="1">
            <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
              <Accordion.Header>Gender page</Accordion.Header>
              <Accordion.Body>
                <Row>
                <Col className='col-md-4'>
                <label>Action</label><span style={{ color: "red", fontWeight: 'bold' }}>  *</span>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                
                <Form.Check type="radio" name="male" id="male" value="yes" label="male" inline
                 // onClick={() => {
                   // window.location.href = "/male";
                  //}}
                />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                <Form.Check type="radio" name="female" id="female" value="no" label="female" inline 
              
                   onClick={() => {
                     window.location.href = "/female";
                   }}
                />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                <div className="right">
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                  
                
                {" "}
                Go{" "}
             
                
                
              </Button>
   
              
            </div>
            
  
             
            
          </Col>
                </Row>
              </Accordion.Body>
            </Accordion.Item>
          </Accordion>
        </div>
        <div className="card-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
                  
};
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily by storing currently selected path in state and then redirecting to this path once the button is clicked as shown below.

**NOTE: This solution is not optimal** because it will reload whole web app everytime you make a redirect, better approach would be using [React Router library](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

```js
const gender = () => {
  const [selectedPath, setSelectedPath] = useState();

  const handleRadioChange = newPath => setSelectedPath(newPath);

  const handleButtonClick = () => { 
    window.href.location = selectedPath;
  }

  return (
    <div className="content-page">
      <div className="card-box pt-3">
        <div className="card-body">
          
          <Accordion defaultActiveKey="1">
            <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
              <Accordion.Header>Gender page</Accordion.Header>
              <Accordion.Body>
                <Row>
                <Col className='col-md-4'>
                <label>Action</label><span style={{ color: "red", fontWeight: 'bold' }}>  *</span>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                
                <Form.Check type="radio" name="male" id="male" value="yes" label="male" inline
                  onClick={() => setSelectedValue("/male")}
                />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                <Form.Check type="radio" name="female" id="female value="no" label="female" inline 
              
                   onClick={() => setSelectedValue("/female")}
                />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                <div className="right">
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
                  
                
                {" "}
                Go{" "}
             
                
                
              </Button>
   
              
            </div>
            
  
             
            
          </Col>
                </Row>
              </Accordion.Body>
            </Accordion.Item>
          </Accordion>
        </div>
        <div className="card-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
                  
};
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `history` instead `window.location.href` to provide better performance. Anyways you could just redirect by using a `switch` or `if/else` Statement.

Pseudocode:

```js
const Form = () => {
   const [gender, setGender] = useState('female')
   const history = useHistory()

   const redirect = () => {
      // WITH IF STATEMENT
      if (gender === 'female') {
         history.push('/female')
      } else {
         history.push('/male')
      }

      // WITH SWITCH STATEMENT
      switch(gender) {
          case 'male':
              history.push('/male')
              break;
          case 'female':
              history.push('/female')
              break;
          default: return
      }
   }

   return (
      <>
        // female gender checkbox
        <Form.Check onClick={() => setGender('female')} />

        // male gender checkbox
        <Form.Check onClick={() => setGender('male')} />

        // submit button
        <Button type="submit" onClick={redirect} />
      </>
   )
}
```